# How to make a record cannot be deleted in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is there any way to make a record that contains the data admin can not be deleted? Anyone who knows please help.

Comment: Please explain more. Cannot be deleted where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you can set status for db field for avoiding permanent delete.

2) use access control to prevent admin from deleting by having a secret super admin.

3) disable delete feature from admin panel.